# Click Form button on my spreadsheet web page (Programmatically)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vba

I have an online web form from google spreadsheets that have a button <kbd>REMITERE</kbd>, like in the image.

I fill out this form with data from an excel workbook with vba, everything is ok but I don't find the name of the button to click on that button with my code.

An idea would be helpful....

This is the code, work perfectly until I try clicking the button: its not there.

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate "...."

ie.Visible = True

While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend


ie.Document.ALL("entry.644871607").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

.............

ie.Document.ALL("Remitere").Click
```

[image: Form button]

Comment: Use appropriate tags for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm back with an answer....

Here is the code for clicking button if anyone have this problem:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonRipple exportInk")(0).Click
```